# How can I align image vertical center in a Linear Layout

Tags: android

I have the following layout, which is 1 icon on the left and 2 text views (stack on top of each other) on the right. I would like to have the text1 vertically center in the panel and when I make the text2 Visible.GONE. Can you please tell me how can i do that?

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_alignParentTop="true" - that's why

Answer (score 15):

All you have to do is, in your first example, to replace `android:gravity` on the ImageView by `android:layout_gravity`. 
That's all :)

Answer (score 10):

I'd change it to  one relative layout with only three views inside. And you can use   `android:layout_centerHorizontal`,   `android:layout_centerVertical` to align stuff as well.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to fix the alignment using the current LinearLayout?